# Вывод кодов ОКВЭД на сайт ( многоуровнеый список)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет. Собственно есть БД кодов ОКВЭД в 2-ух вариантах:
1)  http://prntscr.com/jl30er
Тут все данные в 1 таблице отсортированы по возрастанию
2) 5 отдельных таблиц в которых хранится информация по конкретному уровню.

Нужно организовать что то типо этого http://www.rusprofile.ru/codes/
С выводом 1 уровня кода ( первые 2 цифры) и названия уровня проблем нету.
Проблема состоим в том, чтобы при разворачивании 1 уровня выходили соответсвующие коды ( 3 цифры) и их название.
Если не понятно обьяснил на исходнике все наглядно видно как должно быть.

Comment: Наглядно все расписано и показано https://bezramok-tlt.ru/?mode=2&post=21